# Advanced SSL options in elixir websocket lib

Tags: ssl, websocket, elixir

I'm using this Elixir lib https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket which seems to be by far the most used socket library.

I'm particularly interested about its websocket capabilities (especially the client side) since it offers some SSL layer but, it seems to be impossible to pass some advanced SSL options to the `connect!` functions. For instance, I would like to set some certificate and key files at connect time but the API seems to forbid it. I just can pass `secure: true` as an option but nothing else.

Did I miss something?

Comment: For other people, Guid asked the same thing on github here: https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/issues/68. Looks like it's getting fixed.

Comment: It's *almost* fixed as there are still one option name conflict (`key`) between the web API and the SSL API.

Answer (score 0):

As Johannes pointed out, it's now possible since a recent `master` commit to pass options of the underlying layer through the Web API. The Web API will take only the options that concern itself and pass the rest to the SSL/TCP layer.

However, there's still a small issue about an option whose name exists both in web and in SSL as well. So, for now, you cannot pass an SSL `key` option via the Web API.